# How do internet streaming data feeds work?

Tags: language-agnostic, client, feed

This can be any type of data feed, let's just say for this example stock market data since that's a popular one. But I'm talking about real time data feeds. So it continuously sends data.

I'm trying to understand how this is implemented. Does this happen in some way over http? I just don't get how the clients hook up to the server and the server sends continuous data, can anyone clue me into how this works technically? How might a client hook up to the server? Let's take C# or Java or something. Does this happen over http or maybe some other type of way? please go into details.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really any different from normal HTTP traffic, just longer.

What happens when you open a website? (very rough overview)

1. Your computer contacts a server, establishes a connection.
2. Server starts sending data split into packets to you.
3. Your computer receives the packets, possibly out-of-order and some with significant delay, and re-assembles them into a website.

   - Your computer sends an acknowledgment for received packets.
   - The server will retransmit any packets it hasn't received an acknowledgment for for a significant amount of time, assuming they were dropped on the way.
   - In between receiving packets and/or acknowledgments, both wait.
4. When all data necessary for displaying the site is transferred, your computer thanks the server for its time and disconnects.

If at any point in this process either party stops responding for a significant amount of time, either side may drop the connection, assuming technical difficulties.

What's happening with "streaming data feeds"? (even rougher overview)

1. A client contacts a server, establishing a connection.
2. The server starts sending data split into packets to the client.
3. The client receives the packets, possibly out-of-order and some with significant delay, and re-assembles them.

   - The client sends an acknowledgment for received packets.
   - The server will retransmit any packets it hasn't received an acknowledgment for for a significant amount of time, assuming they were dropped on the way.
   - In between receiving packets and/or acknowledgments, both wait.

The only difference is that the client doesn't hang up on the server, because it's still expecting data and that both aren't as quick to drop the connection.

The thing is that *web servers* (for web *sites*) are specialized for the task of delivering small snippets of data to many people, so they're quick to hang up on you once all data has been sent. Your server script can simply *not quit* though, and the connection will stay alive. Here's a tiny PHP script that will demonstrate that:

```
while (true) {
    echo '.';
    sleep(1);
}
```

This will send a new `.` every second indefinitely (note that the web server needs to be configured appropriately to not terminate the script and to immediately send the output).

Try the [Wikipedia article about TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcp/ip) for the basics and [this article about long-polling/HTTP streaming](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming) for concrete examples.

Comment: but in streaming are they still talking over http (port 80)? what would be an example as to how the client connects to the server in doing this? like could i potentially type in a website address and just get streaming information? (i never saw a website do this)

Comment: @foreyez See update. HTTP is not actually the important part, that's just a data exchange protocol on top of TCP/IP, which handles the actual connection. You can't just connect to any random server that's not supposed to send you information continuously. Websites won't "stream" you information, because a website only has a finite size. But in general, yes, if the server sends information continuously without quitting, this works.